# nextcloud rewrites config permissions after reboot

Tags: php, apache-2.4, arch-linux, nextcloud

Heyhey!

i'm struggling with a permission-problem on my nextcloud instance.

My Setup is

- Manjaro 21.0.7-210614 linux518
- Nextcloud 24.0.3-1
- Apache 2.4.54-1
- php-sqlite 8.1.8-1
- php-intl 8.1.8-1
- php-imagick 3.7.0-2
- php-gd 8.1.8-1
- php-apcu 5.1.21-3
- php-apache 8.1.8-1
- php 8.1.8-1

My config folder keeps rewriting it's permissions and as a result i'm getting an error every day:

```
Cannot write into "config" directory!
This can usually be fixed by giving the web server write access to the config directory. 
But, if you prefer to keep config.php 
file read only, set the option "config_is_read_only" to true in it.
See https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/24/go.php?to=admin-config
```

Every day, my permissions are like that:

```
   /usr/sh/we/ne/config  cls -la                                                         INT ✘  root@cloud 
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   nextcloud     94 B     Sat Aug  6 11:10:29 2022    ./
  rwxr-xr-x   1   root        root          30 B     Sat Aug  6 11:10:29 2022    ../
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   nextcloud      0 B     Tue Jul 19 21:28:06 2022    CAN_INSTALL 
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   nextcloud      1 KiB   Sat Aug  6 10:59:43 2022    config.php 
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   nextcloud     66 KiB   Tue Jul 19 21:28:06 2022    config.sample.php 
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   nextcloud    495 B     Tue Jul 19 21:28:06 2022    .htaccess
```

I have to rewrite them in order to get nextcloud working:

```
   /usr/sh/we/nextcloud/config  cls -la                                                      ✔  root@cloud
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   http     94 B     Sat Aug  6 11:10:29 2022    ./
  rwxr-xr-x   1   root        root     30 B     Sat Aug  6 11:10:29 2022    ../
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   http      0 B     Tue Jul 19 21:28:06 2022    CAN_INSTALL 
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   http      1 KiB   Sat Aug  6 10:59:43 2022    config.php 
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   http     66 KiB   Tue Jul 19 21:28:06 2022    config.sample.php 
  rwxrwxr-x   1   nextcloud   http    495 B     Tue Jul 19 21:28:06 2022    .htaccess
```

User nextcloud is not part of group http!

Strangely the permissions in /etc/webapps/nextcloud are not affected by changing the symlinks. I have to cd into that folder and also change them by hand.

Whats that strange behaviour and how can i get nextcloud to keep my permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only solution is to add the webserver-user to the nextcloud group...

```
usermod -a -G nextcloud http
```